# Group in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to do a simple group but whatever i try nothing is working with mongodb, i need to get total clients in conversation, how do i do it?

```
{message:'',username:'jack',room_id:1},
{message:'',username:'jack',room_id:1},
{message:'',username:'mike',room_id:1},
{message:'',username:'eddy',room_id:1},
{message:'',username:'eddy',room_id:2},
```

I tried this:

```
{$match:{room_id:room_id}},{ "$group" : {username : 1,count:{ $sum:1}}}
```

**the results: participants = {count: null} (but sometimes it give me ={total: 0}**

```
{$match:{room_id:room_id}},{"$group" : {username : '$username',count:{ $sum:1}}}
```

**the results: participants = {count: [4 but should return 3]}**

Answer (score 0):

It could be an error because _id needs to be input, you can just put null though

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Comment: if i put null like this {{
              $match:{
                room_id:room_id
              }
            },{
              "$group" : {
                username : null,
                count:{ $sum:1}
              }
            }}, i get same results : {count:null}

Comment: {$match:{room_id:room_id}},{ "$group" : {_id :{username : null,count:{ $sum:1}}}} worked!

Comment: actually it does not work either, always returns count:1  :(

Comment: no I meant like this ```{$match:{room_id:room_id}},{"$group" : {_id: null, username: '$username',count:{ $sum:1}}```

Comment: return null as before but, i came somehow with this pic of code and looks like it's doing the job... 

{
              $match:{
                room_id:room_id
              }
            },{
              "$group" : {
                _id: {
                  username: '$username',
                },
                count: { $sum: 1 }
              }
            },{
              "$group" : {
                _id: null,
                count: { $sum: 1 }
              }
            }